# Playing audio without freezing draw loop in openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, audio

I'm working on a project in openGL and it needs to be able to play simple sounds (mp3) from file while not interrupting the draw loop.

I've been playing around with a few different libraries (openAL, portaudio) and eventually settled on mpg123 (to load the mp3) and libao to play the mp3 back.

The current playsound function works but it blocks the openGL draw loop (ie. freezes the game) until the audio has completed playing. I have tried messing around with std::thread but it still blocked the draw loop.

Here is the audio playback function I've been testing with:

```
void playSound() {
    mpg123_handle *mh;
    unsigned char *buffer;
    size_t buffer_size;
    size_t done;
    int err;

    int driver;
    ao_device *dev;

    ao_sample_format format;
    int channels, encoding;
    long rate;

    /* initializations */
    ao_initialize();
    driver = ao_default_driver_id();
    mpg123_init();
    mh = mpg123_new(NULL, &err);
    buffer_size = mpg123_outblock(mh);
    buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(unsigned char));

    /* open the file and get the decoding format */
    mpg123_open(mh, "sounds/door.mp3");
    mpg123_getformat(mh, &rate, &channels, &encoding);

    /* set the output format and open the output device */
    format.bits = mpg123_encsize(encoding) * 8;
    format.rate = rate;
    format.channels = channels;
    format.byte_format = AO_FMT_NATIVE;
    format.matrix = 0;
    dev = ao_open_live(driver, &format, NULL);

    /* decode and play */
    while (mpg123_read(mh, buffer, buffer_size, &done) == MPG123_OK)
            ao_play(dev, (char*)buffer, done);

    /* clean up */
    free(buffer);
    ao_close(dev);
    mpg123_close(mh);
    mpg123_delete(mh);
    mpg123_exit();
    ao_shutdown();
}
```

How would I go about fixing this so that my game continues to run smoothly and the audio plays in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should unpack small amount of audio data and feed it to an audio device every frame. 
The main trick is to find out how many samples was played by device already. I'm not sure how you can do this with libao, but it pretty simple with OpenAL.

You can check details here [Play stream in OpenAL library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064742/play-stream-in-openal-library)

Also, you always can use additional thread. It'll be overkill, but very simple to do and can work fine for a small/demo project.

Comment: Despite my +1, I disagree with an additional thread being overkill. Personally, I would suggest that over handling the timing in one thread in the way you initially suggest. Pushing audio data into a synchronized queue on the other thread is relatively easy as far as multi-threading goes, and if the OP does not know enough about the issues of multithreading I would highly recommend studying the topic. When used correctly, the complexity of adding a thread is taking 1 step back to take 4 forward and you can have simpler code overall.

Comment: @Aaron Well, audio streaming is relatively simple task for modern CPU, so separate thread won't do anything most of the time. But, as I said, it's reasonable for a small project.

Comment: Ah, I see. It appears you were speaking from the point of view of the CPU? Indeed, a separate thread is not necessary from that standpoint; the audio is not a bottleneck requiring its own thread. I was thinking more from a logical design point of view. I would use another thread just because, once it is set up, it would allow me to forget about these timing issues since they would not be holding anything up. It does not hurt to have some threads sit idle most of the time. Anyway, after your clarification, I don't think I disagree with you at all.